# PHP Short URLs like on Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, url-rewriting

Does anyone know how to have a kind of URL Shortner?

for example, using PHP rather than having www.domain.com/page.php?seq=1435 to have www.domain.com/rGhpf

Does anyone have any ideas on what i can do with this - any help would be much appreciated

Comment: this can be done using .htaccess rewrite rules

Comment: You can check how [wordpress plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/shorten-url/) do. All relates to your project/framework/etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using Apache's Rewrite urls.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^seq/([0-9/]+)$ /page.php?seq=$1 [L]
```

That means you can goto http://domain.com/seq/1435 instead of http://www.domain.com/page.php?seq=1435

Answer (score 0):

Ensure Apache's mod_rewite is available http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Create a file called .htaccess in the docroot of the site (you can also do this in other directories with other rules)

If script is index.php all okay. No need to continue L=last

If script doesn't exist or directory doesn't exist redirect to index.php (we know its okay) and put requested script in $_GET['seq']

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?seq=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I have tried your code in my .htaccess file.
I have index.php and then on that page, is if i go to page A it would be index.php?p=a
so the p=a is the page which it gets from a mysql database but when i go to domain.com/a rather than domain.com/index.php?p=a i just get the main homepage and not the content of a from the database

Comment: check your rewrite logs. If you don't have any, then add the following 2 lines to your apache config for your site: __RewriteLogLevel 3__ and __RewriteLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/rewrite.log__

Comment: do i add this into the htaccess file?